# Ruby Script to create new model value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Project is the model name and I want to do something like:

```
Project.create(:name => 'projectname', :identifier => 'projectidentifier')
```

This should be done in the terminal through a ruby script. I am not going to use rails console to create it nor use seeds.rb in a db file to migrate this as rake db:seed.

Can someone help. Thanks

Comment: You still gonna need to load rails app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be using rails runner (which essentially loads rails):

```
rails runner your_script.rb
```

The line of code would be a content of that script.

Answer (score 1):

What about a rake task?

on lib/tasks, create a file named **data.rake**, and the content:

```
namespace :data
  desc "Create project data"
  task create_project_data: :environment do
    Project.create(name: 'projectname', identifier: 'projectidentifier')
  end
end
```

And you can run it as any rake task

```
rake data:create_project_data
```

And it will also appear when you list your rake tasks

```
rake -T
```